# Upload JPG image to Twitter

Tags: xcode, image, twitter, upload, jpeg

I'm trying to upload a jpg image to twitter. I can upload the @"icon.png" as many times as I want but can't seem to get a jpg to upload. I always get error 403 back from twitter. This is my code:

```
ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];


UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:file]; //file is the name of a jpg image. If replaced with @"icon.png" the upload works


TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"] 
                                             parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Hello. This is a tweet." forKey:@"status"] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

[postRequest addMultiPartData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) withName:@"media" type:@"multipart/png"]; //I've tried this with UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 80) and multipart/jpg and jpeg to no avail


// Set the account used to post the tweet.
[postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

[postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) 
 {
     NSLog(@"Twitter response, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
 }];
```

Please help!

If I use the below it works

```
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]; //This file is copied to the device when the app is built.
```

But, if I use this is does not work, even though I have confirmed that this path and file name does intact pull up the image

```
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", dir, file]];
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

/// SOLUTION
I may be an idiot, please don't crucify me, but here is what I needed to change the UIImage to

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", dir, file]];
```

This allows both PNG and JPG to upload without issue. Stupid mistake but at least it's working now. Thanks for the replies!!

Comment: Check your `twitterAccount` because `403` is authentication error.

Comment: Yes, I have, it's set for both read and write access. The app is also allowed access. Like I said earlier, I can upload the icon.png with no trouble. As soon as I try to upload a jpg, the file format I need, it returns 403. Very frustrating! Thanks for the prompt reply! Incidentally, the return I get uploading a png is 200. I've just confirmed this again but uploading another png.

Comment: For the jpg, are you passing imageNamed just the name of the file, or are you also adding the .jpg extension?

Comment: The file name is something along the lines of this 3521af2f5a31df18809c165096811089.JPG (actual file name). The name is a hash of the actual file data to ensure each jpg is unique, always. So to answer yes, it does have the ext. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Before posting, try verifying that the image you get from `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` is not `nil`. There could be something wrong with your jpg images.

Comment: This has been verified. I can successfully NSLog the file name to show what it is. The image name is also stored in a plist and the only way the class can get called before starting the upload is if a method can file the name, read some data and start the process. I'm currently doing this successfully with Dropbox, Evernote, Facebook and Email. Twitter is the only one giving me trouble. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, my extensions are in caps. As in jpg = JPG and png = PNG. Could this cause the issue or is this irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

The 403 error means the error comes from Twitter; you cannot share the same content twice from the same Twitter account.  If you want to upload the same picture, then you must first remove it from the Twitter account, then try to upload it again.  Otherwise, upload a different picture.